# Function Composition, Derivatives, Gradient, Hessian

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis, function-and-relation-composition, hessian-matrix

Here's the problem:

Let $f : R^n \to R$ be a twice continuously differentiable function. Let $\phi(t) = f(u + td)$ be a composition function from $R$ to $R$, with given vectors $u, d \in R^n$. Express $\phi′(t)$ and $\phi′′(t)$ in terms of the gradient and Hessian of $f$ and the vectors $u, d$.

It's been awhile since I've taken calculus, and I'm unsure if i'm approaching this correctly. Would someone mind checking my work and letting me know what I might be doing wrong?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArdG1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Well, $\phi$ is just a function of one variable. By chain rule, $$\phi'(t)=\nabla f(u+td)\cdot d.$$ What can you say now about $\phi''$?

Comment: I posted an image with my work and my answers.

Why is it ∇f(u+td) and not ∇f(u+td)^T?

For ϕ′', I got ∇^2f(u+td)^T⋅d

Comment: $T$ for transpose? I guess I'm just assuming you can dot them without taking the transpose. This is not important, really.

Comment: Ah! You're using ⋅ for dot product, not multiplication. Then I guess I got the right answer?

Comment: Right, dot product, since the gradient and $d$ are vectors

Answer (score 0):

$\phi'(t)=Df_{u+td}(d)$ and $\phi''(t)=D^2f_{u+td}(d,d)$. Let $H(v)=[\dfrac{\partial ^2f}{\partial v_i\partial v_j}]$ be the Hessian matrix of $f$ in $v$. In other words, $\phi''(t)=d^TH(u+td)d$.